# How to convert wstring to string as escapes

Tags: c++, boost, wstring

I have a wstring, what's the best way to convert it to string in escaped form like `\u043d\u043e\u043c\u0430` ?

The one below works but does not seem to be the best:

```
string output; 
for (wchar_t chr : wtst) {
    char code[7];
    sprintf(code,"\\u%0.4X",chr);
    output += code;
}
```

Comment: If it "does not seem to be the best", might I ask what you're (a) comparing it to, and (b) why you're not using *that*?

Comment: it's not compact, takes several lines of code. I think there may be already some one-line converter in boost or std.

Comment: There is no converter for this in the standard library, and if there is one in boost, it would be hard-pressed to be more compact than six lines of implementation code. The *caller* side (you) would, of course, be significantly compacted by a ratio of approx. 83% if such a converter *does* exist. Then again, the dependency introduced will assuredly be larger than six lines. Could you make *this* more efficient? Surely. Start with `.reserve()`ing some capacity.

Comment: @WhozCraig could you make your comment an answer? and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A less compact but faster version that a) allocates ahead of time and b) avoids the cost of printf re-interpreting the format string every iteration, c) avoiding the function call overhead to printf.

```
std::wstring wstr(L"\x043d\x043e\x043c\x0430");
std::string sstr;
// Reserve memory in 1 hit to avoid lots of copying for long strings.
static size_t const nchars_per_code = 6;
sstr.reserve(wstr.size() * nchars_per_code); 
char code[nchars_per_code];
code[0] = '\\';
code[1] = 'u';
static char const* const hexlut = "0123456789abcdef";
std::wstring::const_iterator i = wstr.begin();
std::wstring::const_iterator e = wstr.end();
for (; i != e; ++i) {
    unsigned wc = *i;
    code[2] = (hexlut[(wc >> 12) & 0xF]);
    code[3] = (hexlut[(wc >> 8) & 0xF]);
    code[4] = (hexlut[(wc >> 4) & 0xF]);
    code[5] = (hexlut[(wc) & 0xF]);
    sstr.append(code, code + nchars_per_code);
}
```

Comment: You can also speed this up further by using a pointer to directly write into the string.  Not all compilers will be able to fully inline functions calls within basic_string::append.